# Remove first letter in string of every index in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

i have a a data model like this:

```
[#hello, #world, #foo, #bar]
```

I want to loop through each one of them and remove the number symbol, How di i go about his?

Answer (score 4):

Loop over the *Array* with your favourite method (e.g. [`arr.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) and use [`str.slice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```
['#hello', '#world', '#foo', '#bar'].map(function (e) {
    return e.slice(1);
}); // ["hello", "world", "foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through each string of the array and perform a  operation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr